# I would like to ask any interested reader about "Quantum Bidding in Bridge"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

see http://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.021047

I would like to see how specific examples are worked out. Specifically, details on how the quantum protocol in figure 1. of the above paper works.

Comment: You should specify better your doubts.

Comment: I'm trying to work out an explicit matrix representation. This would entail choosing a specific Bell state for the entangled pair, which the authors wave off. I also can't tell if \bigoplus denotes a direct sum or a Kronecker sum.